# How does Samsung Health count steps without long background services?

Tags: android, mobile, android-service, android-sensors, samsung-mobile

I'm developing a health application that record the user's steps.
I'm really searching for a couple of weeks how to run this in the background and I have no solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

runing service for long time without draing battery and system resource was hardest thing i faced in programming and finally today i found the best solution for my idea
thank to Coding in Flow channel

> StepsService::class

```
class MainActivity() : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(
            flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,
            "background_service"
        ).setMethodCallHandler(
            MethodCallHandler { call: MethodCall, result: 
              MethodChannel.Result ->
                if ((call.method == "start")) {
                    //start Service.
                    val i: Intent = Intent(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        StepsService::class.java
                    )
                    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, i)

                }
                result.success(1)
            }

            //start Service.

        )
    }
}
```

> StepsService::class

```
/** The service is starting, due to a call to startService()  */
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Log.v("Service", "Start")
    sensorManager = getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
    stepCounterSensor = sensorManager!!.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)
    stepDetectorSensor = sensorManager!!.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR)
    sensorManager!!.registerListener(this, stepCounterSensor, 0)
    sensorManager!!.registerListener(this, stepDetectorSensor, 0)

    //currentStepCount = 0;
    currentStepsDetected = 0
    stepCounter = 0
    newStepCounter = 0

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------- \\
    // ___ (3) start handler ___ \\
    // remove any existing callbacks to the handler
    handler.removeCallbacks(updateBroadcastData)
    // call our handler with or without delay.
    handler.post(updateBroadcastData) // 0 seconds
    // ___________________________________________________________________________ \\

    val notificationIntent = Intent(
        this,
        MainActivity::class.java
    )
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0, notificationIntent, 0
    )

    val notification : Notification;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
           notification = Notification.Builder(this, channelId)
               .setContentTitle("$currentStepsDetected Steps")
               .setContentText("Target Steps 7500")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
               .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
            .build()
    }else{
      notification = Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Example Service")
            .setContentText("description")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
            .build()
    }

    startForeground(1, notification)

    return START_NOT_STICKY
}
```

[reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbpD5RZtbCc&t=9s)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30427201)

Comment: I'm new here so im sorry , thank you